# How to set maximum date upto 7 days from current date in Datepicker?

Tags: android

> I want to set maximum date upto 7 days from current date

```
public void showDateTimePicker() {
        final Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                
                }, currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), currentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false).show();

            }
        }, currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), currentDate.get(Calendar.DATE));
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate((System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000) + (1000*60*60*24*7));
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

> If I go by above method app crashes when it exceeds months. How can I achieve this? Crash is as below:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.SimpleMonthView.getMonthHeight()' on a null object reference at android.widget.DayPickerView.onLayout(DayPickerView.java:232) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389) at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389) at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270) at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1660) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389) at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829) at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673) at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389) at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389) at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389) at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389) at com.android.internal.widget.AlertDialogLayout.setChildFrame(AlertDialogLayout.java:358) at com.android.internal.widget.AlertDialogLayout.onLayout(AlertDialogLayout.java:351) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389) at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389) at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389) at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332) at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270) at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844) at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171) at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972) at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796) at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731) at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Answer (score 0):

Try This
STEP 1-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val button: AppCompatButton = findViewById(R.id.click)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        val mYear: Int
        val mMonth: Int
        val mDay: Int

        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        mYear = c[Calendar.YEAR]
        mMonth = c[Calendar.MONTH]
        mDay = c[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH]


        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
            this,
            { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                button.text = dayOfMonth.toString() + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year
            },
            mYear,
            mMonth,
            mDay
        )
        datePickerDialog.datePicker.minDate =
            c.timeInMillis
        datePickerDialog.datePicker.maxDate =
            ((c.timeInMillis) + ((1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)))
        datePickerDialog.show()


    }
}
```

}

STEP 2- activity_main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/click"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST" />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```